# Java GUI alternatives

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I write applications in Java, and I'm looking for ways to speedup GUI programming. Binding frameworks help, but the particular application I'm working on now wouldn't benefit too much from that (it doesn't display a lot of data, just a lot of ways to manipulate the data). I feel like I spend way too much time writing boiler-plate GUI code, like adding action listeners, laying out components, etc. While I'm not a C# developer, I've heard XAML works very well and have seen JAXX, which appears to be similar to XAML. I'm also looking at the Groovy Swing Builder. It just seems like there are so many options, maybe even too many.

Can anyone share their thoughts on alternatives to hand writing simple Java UI code?

Also, I'd be interested in discussing how to migrate existing Java Swing code to use some of these options.

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: I've avoided writing Java GUI applications whenever possible due to this. I'm interested in seeing suggestions as well.

Comment: I had the same feeling until I try using GUI creator of Netbeans. Also, playing with JavaFX a bit and I think it can really speed up the GUI (but didn't have much time playing with it yet).

Comment: I've considered using GUI creators, but I guess I just feel like there is too much GUI code generated (similar to hand writing it). True the GUI creator helps speed up the process but it doesn't eliminate the boiler plate code that tends to appear all over the place (I know that under the hood things like XAML still generate the code at runtime, but at least you don't have to maintain the code).

Comment: You don't have to "maintain the code" generated by the UI builder. You maintain the XML document that Netbeans creates using its editor. Used well Netbeans can create a good, easy to maintain UI. But you have to accept that the UI will be created & maintained using just the Netbeans editor. The boilerplate exists but it is collapsed and to be frank if you are looking at almost any code in the generated .java files you are using the UI builder wrong.

Comment: True, but I also don't like the idea of being tied into Netbeans. Not everyone here (including myself) uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) is a Groovy framework for creating Java desktop applications. Admittedly, if you don't already know Groovy, you'll need to learn (some parts of) a new language to use it effectively, but the enhanced productivity is worth the effort in my opinion.

Comment: Agree. When I wrote this question, I was still somewhat new to groovy, but have been writing it for the last few years. Griffon is a bit more mature now and seems like a reasonable framework to use for desktop environments.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can build a Griffon application with pure Java too, see http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/guide/tips.html#nonGroovyArtifacts for reference.

Answer (score 10):

How about using [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)?

It is extremely simple to learn and use.
I strongly recommend it to you. In my last project, it helped me to reduce much time to implement lots of GUI.

Comment: MigLayout has made development very simple and easy for me.

Answer (score 7):

Layouts:

For layouts, I have abandoned the JDK Layout Managers in favor of the [JGoodies Forms](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/) tool. I find it much more effective. It reads at a higher level, and reduces significantly the amount of code related to layouts.

Comment: Agreed. I use that as well. Definitely helps.

Comment: DesignGridLayout can also help a lot for the layout aspects, if you have only forms in your UI.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using [Clojure](http://clojure.org)
It allows you to write Java GUIs quickly without the boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use an IDE with GUI builder.

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html) and [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) have very good GUI builders, they allow you to automatically bind objects and would reduce tremendously the amount of effort needed to create a GUI as opposed of doing it completely by hand.

Comment: As a fan of UI builders I do feel I should add - If you use one don't throw good standards out of the window. When you add a widget always name it well and avoid the double-click-auto-add-listener rubbish.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with others that tying down to NetBeans seems dangerous - especially when working with other developers. I've used the (commercial) Swing Designer (by "instantiations") plugin for Eclipse with quite a lot of success - the thing I like about it is that it round-trips, generating code that you are free to alter by hand. Not perfect, but a good time-saver.

But the biggest difference in my Swing programming came with the discovery of better layout managers. I went from FormLayout (good), to TableLayout (better), but now I don't use anything but MiGLayout (incredible).

Answer (score 2):

You can try ZK(the best open source Java framework for building enterprise web and mobile apps).
http://www.zkoss.org/

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in GUI programming, but have you tried using [NetBeans as a platform](http://www.netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html) for your app?

Comment: It seems to be for larger applications. It might be counterproductive. See this "intro": http://netbeans.dzone.com/videos/free-netbeans-platform-crash